# How to add the command line inputs

Tags: shell

I need to perform a calculation(addition/multiplication) using the command line input.
For an example: I'm executing the below `./calculation.sh 1 2 3 4 5`. It has to sum up the output as 15. Any idea to this ? I've tried with the below logic but couldn't make it.

```
set -x
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    expr $1 + 1
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OUTPUT=0 
for i in $*; do
    OUTPUT=$(($OUTPUT + $i)) 
done
echo $OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to make use of a variable to save the result of `expr`.  Moreover, `+1` doesn't seem to make much sense.  You probably wanted to replace that with the variable itself.
2. You need to print the variable at the end.

Try:

```
set -x
res=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    res=`expr $1 + $res`
    shift
done
echo $res
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
set -x
sum=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    sum=$(expr "$sum" + "$1")
    shift
done
echo "sum: $sum"
```

And it's simpler in bash:

```
sum=0
for i; do
    (( sum += i ))
done
echo "sum: $sum"
```